# Аутентификация и авторизация уже залогиненного пользователя

Tags: php, cookie, авторизация, сессия, аутентификация

Как сделать так, что при следующих входах залогиненный пользователь был уже авторизован (если в последнее посещение он не вышел из аккаунта)? (Вопрос важный, если можете отредактируйте вопрос, а то у меня проблемы с формулировкой-не хватает словарного IT запаса)

Comment: Точно так же, как и при первом входе: записать информацию о пользователе [в сессию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php) (например id пользователя или как вы там собираетесь его идентифицировать), при следующих входах читать эти записанные данные из сессии и делать с ними что требуется

Answer (score 0):

Возможно часть этого для Вас избыточно, но можете оставить только то, что нужно

1. После авторизации пользователя, генерируете ему `уникальный` код сессии. Сохраняете ее в БД.
2. По тому же принципу генерируете `cookie` (кука). Куку сохраняете в браузер.
3. При каждом обращении авторизованного пользователя проверяете п.4,5,6 и далее, если все нормально обновляете в БД время последней активности пользователя, если нет то п.7
4. При повторном входе пользователя проверяете существует ли код сессии в `$_SESSION`. 5) Если да, проверяете есть ли такой код в БД.
5. Если да, проверяете не истекло ли время жизни данной сессии (текущее время минус время последней активности пользователя) т.к в данное время установленное в `php.ini` может сильно отличаться в большую сторону от того которое Вы установили у себя на сайте (например в `php.ini` - 2 часа, а у Вас если пользователь ничего не делал 30 минут то Вы его разрегистрируете)
6. Если время сессии истекло, повторяете все тоже самое для куки (есть ли кука в браузере, есть ли она в БД, не истекло ли время и тп), если все ок - не забудьте заново выдать новый `уникальный` код сессии, обновить куку в браузере и обновить время последней активности пользователя в БД
7. В результате либо пускаете пользователя куда следует как авторизованного, даже если он какое-то долгое время не был на сайте (авторизуете по куке), либо отправляете заново логиниться.