# Прозрачная поддержка sid

Tags: php, сессия

На [Авторизация на PHP](https://otus.ru/nest/post/882/) в функции login используется оператор

```js
ini_set ("session.use_trans_sid", true)
```

Что он делает (нашел на https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid, но не понял, что такое прозрачная поддержка sid)?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.idpassing.php

Comment: Код в этой «Авторизации на PHP» жутко некачественный и полон детских ошибок, лучше её выкинуть и забыть

Comment: @andreymal приведите качественные страницы по авторизации\регистрации и в чем некачественность кода на моей странице

Comment: Вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196180/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F/ я примерно описал алгоритм авторизации пользователя, посмотрите, возможно что-то из этого Вам пригодится. Хотя, не исключаю, что его тоже обвинят в `детских` ошибках :)